# Panorama application and images

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

i try to do a panorama application where when you tap an item in the listbox,it open a new page.
So the list box is composed of an image and a texbox, qhen i tap i want to bring the name of image into the new page. 
Any advice?? (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some more details. What you have already tried? Where are you stuck? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
               <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Tag="{Binding ImageName}" Tap="Image_Tap"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

In the code behind

```
private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   Image img = sender as Image;
   String name = img.Tag.ToString();
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml?ImageName="+name,UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On Page2.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        String Name = NavigationContext.QueryString["ImageName"];
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters as it is shown in [this example](http://xamlgeek.net/2010/10/13/parameters-and-navigation-in-windows-phone-7/).

So, on Tap event you need to get the image name, save it to any string and pass as a query parameter:

```
var url = "/Views/PageName.xaml?imageName=" + imageName;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url ,UriKind.Relative));
```